# Effect of --test_env and --test_arg on bazel cache

Tags: bazel

I'm naively passing along some variable test metadata to some `py_test` targets to inject that metadata into some test result artifacts that later get uploaded to the cloud. I'm doing so using either the `--test_env` or `--test_arg` values at the `bazel test` invocation.

Would this variable data negatively affect the way test results are cached such that running the same test back to back would effectively disturb the bazel cache?

Answer (score 1):

## Command Line Inputs

Command line inputs can indeed disturb cache hits. Consider the following set of executions

**BUILD** file

```py
py_test(
    name = "test_inputs",
    srcs = ["test_inputs.py"],
    deps = [
        ":conftest",
        "@pytest",
    ],
)

py_library(
    name = "conftest",
    srcs = ["conftest.py"],
    deps = [
        "@pytest",
    ],
)
```

**Test module**

```py
import sys
import pytest

def test_pass():
    assert True

def test_arg_in(request):
    assert request.config.getoption("--metadata")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    ret_code = pytest.main([__file__, "--log-level=ERROR"] + args)
    sys.exit(ret_code)
```

### First execution

```
$ bazel test //bazel_check:test_inputs --test_arg --metadata=abc
INFO: Analyzed target //bazel_check:test_inputs (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
INFO: 2 processes: 1 internal (50.00%), 1 local (50.00%).
INFO: Cache hit rate for remote actions: -- (0 / 0)
INFO: Total action wall time 0.40s
INFO: Critical path 0.57s (setup 0.00s, action wall time 0.00s)
INFO: Elapsed time 0.72s (preparation 0.12s, execution 0.60s)
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
//bazel_check:test_inputs                                                  PASSED in 0.4s

Executed 1 out of 1 test: 1 test passes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
```

### Second execution: same argument value, cache hit!

```
$ bazel test //bazel_check:test_inputs --test_arg --metadata=abc
INFO: Analyzed target //bazel_check:test_inputs (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal (100.00%).
INFO: Cache hit rate for remote actions: -- (0 / 0)
INFO: Total action wall time 0.00s
INFO: Critical path 0.47s (setup 0.00s, action wall time 0.00s)
INFO: Elapsed time 0.61s (preparation 0.12s, execution 0.49s)
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
//bazel_check:test_inputs                                         (cached) PASSED in 0.4s

Executed 0 out of 1 test: 1 test passes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

### Third execution: new argument value, no cache hit

```
$ bazel test //bazel_check:test_inputs --test_arg --metadata=kk
INFO: Analyzed target //bazel_check:test_inputs (0 packages loaded, 93 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
INFO: 2 processes: 1 internal (50.00%), 1 local (50.00%).
INFO: Cache hit rate for remote actions: -- (0 / 0)
INFO: Total action wall time 0.30s
INFO: Critical path 0.54s (setup 0.00s, action wall time 0.00s)
INFO: Elapsed time 0.71s (preparation 0.14s, execution 0.57s)
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
//bazel_check:test_inputs                                                  PASSED in 0.3s

Executed 1 out of 1 test: 1 test passes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
```

### Fourth execution: reused same argument as first two runs

Interestingly enough there is no cache hit despite the result being cached earlier. Somehow it did not persist.

```
$ bazel test //bazel_check:test_inputs --test_arg --metadata=abc
INFO: Analyzed target //bazel_check:test_inputs (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
INFO: 2 processes: 1 internal (50.00%), 1 local (50.00%).
INFO: Cache hit rate for remote actions: -- (0 / 0)
INFO: Total action wall time 0.34s
INFO: Critical path 0.50s (setup 0.00s, action wall time 0.00s)
INFO: Elapsed time 0.71s (preparation 0.17s, execution 0.55s)
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
//bazel_check:test_inputs                                                  PASSED in 0.3s

Executed 1 out of 1 test: 1 test passes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
```

## Environment Inputs

The same exact behavior applies for `--test_env` inputs

```py
import os
import sys
import pytest

def test_pass():
    assert True

def test_env_in():
    assert os.environ.get("META_ENV")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    ret_code = pytest.main([__file__, "--log-level=ERROR"] + args)
    sys.exit(ret_code)
```

## First execution

```
$ bazel test //bazel_check:test_inputs --test_env META_ENV=33
INFO: Build option --test_env has changed, discarding analysis cache.
INFO: Analyzed target //bazel_check:test_inputs (0 packages loaded, 7285 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
INFO: 2 processes: 1 internal (50.00%), 1 local (50.00%).
INFO: Cache hit rate for remote actions: -- (0 / 0)
INFO: Total action wall time 0.29s
INFO: Critical path 0.66s (setup 0.00s, action wall time 0.00s)
INFO: Elapsed time 1.26s (preparation 0.42s, execution 0.84s)
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
//bazel_check:test_inputs                                                  PASSED in 0.3s

Executed 1 out of 1 test: 1 test passes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
```

### Second execution: same env value, cache hit!

```
$ bazel test //bazel_check:test_inputs --test_env META_ENV=33
INFO: Analyzed target //bazel_check:test_inputs (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal (100.00%).
INFO: Cache hit rate for remote actions: -- (0 / 0)
INFO: Total action wall time 0.00s
INFO: Critical path 0.49s (setup 0.00s, action wall time 0.00s)
INFO: Elapsed time 0.67s (preparation 0.15s, execution 0.52s)
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
//bazel_check:test_inputs                                         (cached) PASSED in 0.3s

Executed 0 out of 1 test: 1 test passes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

### Third execution: new env value, no cache hit

```
$ bazel test //bazel_check:test_inputs --test_env META_ENV=44
INFO: Build option --test_env has changed, discarding analysis cache.
INFO: Analyzed target //bazel_check:test_inputs (0 packages loaded, 7285 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
INFO: 2 processes: 1 internal (50.00%), 1 local (50.00%).
INFO: Cache hit rate for remote actions: -- (0 / 0)
INFO: Total action wall time 0.29s
INFO: Critical path 0.62s (setup 0.00s, action wall time 0.00s)
INFO: Elapsed time 1.22s (preparation 0.39s, execution 0.83s)
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
//bazel_check:test_inputs                                                  PASSED in 0.3s

Executed 1 out of 1 test: 1 test passes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
```

### Fourth execution: reused same env value as first two runs

```
$ bazel test //bazel_check:test_inputs --test_env META_ENV=33
INFO: Build option --test_env has changed, discarding analysis cache.
INFO: Analyzed target //bazel_check:test_inputs (0 packages loaded, 7285 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
INFO: 2 processes: 1 internal (50.00%), 1 local (50.00%).
INFO: Cache hit rate for remote actions: -- (0 / 0)
INFO: Total action wall time 0.28s
INFO: Critical path 0.66s (setup 0.00s, action wall time 0.00s)
INFO: Elapsed time 1.25s (preparation 0.40s, execution 0.85s)
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
//bazel_check:test_inputs                                                  PASSED in 0.3s

Executed 1 out of 1 test: 1 test passes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
```